# error running vscode-mssql extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

would like to learn vscode extensions by downloading vscode-mssql-master extension from github and running it.

But get "gulp is not recognized as internal or external command" error when I press F5 to run the extension from the vscode editor.

I copied the github zip file folder to a folder on my PC.  Then started cmd.exe, cd to that directory, and run "npm install" to install all dependencies. Last step is start vscode, change folder to the folder with the extension, then press F5 to run.

gulp along with a bunch of other dependencies is in the node_modules sub folder.

Why would gulp not be found?

the error is:
The preLaunchTask 'cover:disable' terminated with exit code 1.
'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

ok. did not read the instructions here:https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/contributing

would add that you first have to copy the repo from github to your PC.